# Does the disease model of addiction presume that free will exists?

Tags: addiction, free-will, model

I have been studying the disease model of addiction; and from what I have read [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.samhsa.gov/sites/default/files/programs_campaigns/02._webcast_2_resources.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiYp9LF4NH_AhWfIkQIHRMtDxYQFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw3QDGFnkxLY3SV0B6tcmwpp), free will is part of the disease model of addiction.

That linked document cites the following:

> “Addiction Is a Disease of Free Will”. A video presentation in which Dr. Nora Volkow, Director of NIDA, addresses the question of why addiction is a disease, and how addiction as a disease impairs the free will and decision-making abilities of those affected.

I am not sure if it's generally agreed that free will existing is part of the paradigm of the disease model of addiction.

I am under the impression that the answer to my question is "no" because no one has discovered a biological basis for free will in order to include it in the disease model of addiction. Thus, the linked government website is pushing free will propaganda.

It seems to me that the disease model of addiction means to be as scientific as possible. For free will to be included in it seems for the disease model of addiction to make a prediction about how addiction works that cannot be tested for falsifiability.